# Displaying series of bitmap in form of a movie

Tags: matlab

I have a series of bitmap files that I want to display on a GUI, like a movie.

But the files will not be available all at once, as the incoming bitmaps need to be demodulated.

E.g
Bitmap -> Modulate -> Channel -> Demodulate -> Bitmap -> Display

Now I have 2 questions:

1) Does any of the matlab commands read from a buffer (maybe circular buffer??) to display the bitmaps? As I have an idea to store the received bitmaps into a buffer.

2) Is it possible to demodulate and display **concurrently** in matlab?

Or I need to use Java or C++ to achieve the above tasks?

Answer (score 0):

1) How do you intend to read this data?  From a pipe, socket, one file per image?  Any of these work for you, then all you need to do is avoid closing the file after reading one bitmap (and perhaps doing some extra coding to block when the next image is not ready yet).

2) No.  All Matlab computation happens in a single thread (from a user's perspective).

2.a) If you can do the demodulation or display in a mex function, then the mex function is free to spawn extra threads and do whatever it pleases.

If you do the display in Matlab, don't forget to call DRAWNOW.

Comment: I intend to create a buffer and put the bitmap into it with actually saving a .bmp for each bitmap.

I will look into the mex function part.